# jQuery sequential looping

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

I have 4 boxes and I want the content to change sequentialy in box order - 
Box 1 has fruit and lizard
Box 2 fruit and lizard
Box 3 fruit and lizard
Box 4 fruit and lizard

On load you only see fruits with all lizards hidden with CSS
Box1: fruit changes to lizard
1 secs later
Box2: fruit changes to lizard
1 secs later
Box3: fruit changes to lizard
1 secs later
Box4: fruit changes to lizard
This is where I am at and I cant seem to get it to loop through:

```
x = 1;      
j = x + 1;

for (var i = 1; i<8; i++) { 
       setInterval(function() {
            $("#imager"+x).delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
            $("#imager"+j).delay(1000).fadeIn(300);
        },1000); 
    };

<div class="holder">                
    <ul>
        <li class="itemer">
            <img src="images/fruit.jpg" alt="fruit" id="imager1" />
        </li>
        <li class="itemer">
            <img src="images/lizard.jpg" alt="lizard" id="imager2" class="hide" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="holder">                
    <ul>
        <li  class="itemer">
            <img src="images/fruit.jpg" alt="fruit" id="imager3" />
        </li>
        <li class="itemer">
            <img src="images/lizard.jpg" alt="lizard" id="imager4" class="hide" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="holder">                
    <ul>
        <li class="itemer">
            <img src="images/fruit.jpg" alt="fruit" id="imager5" />
        </li>
        <li class="itemer">
            <img src="images/lizard.jpg" alt="lizard" id="imager6" class="hide" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="holder">                
    <ul>
        <li class="itemer">
            <img src="images/fruit.jpg" alt="fruit" id="imager7" />
        </li>
        <li class="itemer">
            <img src="images/lizard.jpg" alt="lizard" id="imager8" class="hide" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the call is asynchronous, you can't run a traditional for loop.  Try using a recursive call, so that the next iteration starts when the current one is finished:

```
var i = 1;
var nextIteration = function() {
    $("#imager"+i).fadeOut(300, function() {
        i++;
        $("#imager"+i).fadeIn(300);
        i++;
        setTimeout(nextIteration, 1000);
    });
}; 

setTimeout(nextIteration, 4000);​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2BsKW/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an "index" of the elements you want to show and hide, and later toggle them visible using [jQuery.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), later on you can use its callback to invoke the next element.

```
var divs = $('.holder');
var div_idx = 0;

function nextDiv()
{
    return divs[div_idx++ % divs.length];
}


var toggleHolder = function(){
    $(nextDiv()).toggle("slow",toggleHolder);
};  
$(nextDiv()).toggle("slow", toggleHolder);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then an animation delay, just extend the Timeout period

```
var imageIndex = 0;
var imageInterval = setInterval(function(){
                       $("#imager"+(++imageIndex)).fadeOut(300);
                       $("#imager"+(++imageIndex)).fadeOut(300);
                       if (imageIndex == 8) clearInterval(imageInterval);
                    }, 1000);
```

-- OR --

```
var imageIndex = 0;
for (var i=0; i < 8; i=i+2) {
     setTimeout(function(){
         $("#imager"+(++imageIndex)).fadeOut(300);
         $("#imager"+(++imageIndex)).fadeOut(300);
     }, (i+1)/2*1000);
}
```

-- OR --

```
function toggleImage(x, y, delay){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#imager"+x).fadeOut(300);
      $("#imager"+y).fadeOut(300);
   }, delay);
}

for (var i=1; i < 8; i=i+2) {
    toggleImage(i, i+1, (i+1)/2*1000);
}
```

-- OR --

```
for (var i=1; i < 8; i=i+2) {
   (function(x, y){
      setTimeout(function(){
         $("#imager"+x).fadeOut(300);
         $("#imager"+y).fadeOut(300);
      }, y/2*1000);
   })(i, i+1);
```

-- OR --

```
$([1,3,5,7]).each(function(index, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#imager"+value).fadeOut(300);
        $("#imager"+value+1).fadeOut(300);
    }, (value+1)/2*1000);
});
```